# Sencha Touch - Setting properties for a group of items

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a simple fieldset with several fields, many of which will share some properties. I could perhaps define some extension of the Sencha Touch textfield class, but I imagine that's overkill. What's an easy way to set the common properties?

For example, I could repeat all common properties in each item, but that becomes unnecessarily large...

```
        xtype:  'fieldset',
        id:     'fieldset',
        title:  'My Form Title',

        items: [
            {
                xtype:      'textfield',
                required:       true,
                labelAlign:     'left',
                height:     '50',
                ui:         'customUI',
                id:         'email',
                name:       'email',
                label:      'Email'
            },
            {
                xtype:      'textfield',
                required:       true,
                labelAlign:     'left',
                height:     '50',
                ui:         'customUI',
                inputType:  'password',
                id:         'password',
                name :      'password',
                label:      'Password'
            }
            // More fields
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to just use `defaults`. They'll be applied to the object's items unless overridden. So, with your code, it would look something like this:

```
    xtype:  'fieldset',
    id:     'fieldset',
    title:  'My Form Title',

    // Place your default properties here
    defaults:
    {
            xtype:      'textfield',
            required:       true,
            labelAlign:     'left',
            height:     '50',
            ui:         'customUI',
    },

    items: [
        {
            id:         'email',
            name:       'email',
            label:      'Email'
        },
        {
            inputType:  'password',
            id:         'password',
            name :      'password',
            label:      'Password'
        }
        // More fields
    ]
```